# Xcode AVKit Error: Could not build module 'MediaToolBox'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, avkit

I'm simply trying to put a Video Player in my app, importing 'AVFoundation' and 'AVKit', but Xcode is giving me several errors where I have no idea why.

```
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
```

I will attach a photo of the errors. The ones highlighted in green I managed to fix simply by adding 'import AVFoundation' inside the View, however, I don't know how to fix the others.

I believe this is purely an error in XCode, and not in my code, for this reason, I don't believe it is necessary to insert the code here, as it would be a waste of time.

[image: errors]

I'm on macOS 12.6.7 and Xcode 14.2.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by uninstalling Xcode and installing again from the App Store.

I don't know if this somehow caused a problem, but my Xcode was downloaded outside of the App Store on "xcorereleases".

Comment: Only download xCode from AppStore or Apple downloads.